# Ruby method returning hash value as {}

Tags: ruby, hash, return, instantiation

The variable `value` in the `initialize` method of `LocationList` is populated in line 014.  These changes are relected by the `print` statement in line 015, but the `return` in line 016 thinks the hash is still empty (scroll right to see return value after `=>`).

```
def random_point
  x = rand * 2.0 - 1.0
  y = rand * 2.0 - 1.0
  until x**2 + y**2 < 1.0
    x = rand * 2.0 - 1.0
    y = rand * 2.0 - 1.0
  end
  return [x, y]
end

class LocationList < Hash
  def initialize(node_list)
    value = {}
    node_list.each {|node| value[node] = random_point }
    print value
    return value
  end
end

z = ["moo", "goo", "gai", "pan"]

LocationList.new(z)
#=> {"moo"=>[0.17733298257484997, 0.39221824315332987], "goo"=>[-0.907202436634851, 0.3589265999520428], "gai"=>[0.3910479677151635, 0.5624531973759821], "pan"=>[-0.37544369339427974, -0.7603500269538608]}=> {}
```

Doing substantially the same thing in a global function yields the intended return value:

```
def foo(node_list)
  value = {}
  node_list.each {|node| value[node] = random_point }
  return value
end

foo(z)
#=> {"moo"=>[-0.33410735869573926, -0.4087709899603238], "goo"=>[0.6093966465651919, 0.6349767372996336], "gai"=>[0.718925625951371, -0.6726652512124924], "pan"=>[0.08604969147566277, -0.518636160280254]}
```

Comment: The `initialize` method is not supposed to return any value. Store the hash in an instance variable instead and read it after instantiating the object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're creating a new Hash that you call `value` in your `initialize` method, rather than initializing `self`. Illustrating this inline:

```
class LocationList < Hash
  def initialize(node_list)
    # self is already a LocationList, which is a Hash

    value={}
    # value is now a new Hash

    node_list.each {|node| value[node]=random_point}
    # value now has keys set

    return value
    # value is now discarded
    # LocationList.new returns the constructed object; it does not return
    # the result of LocationList#initialize
  end
end
```

Try this instead:

```
class LocationList < Hash
  def initialize(node_list)
    node_list.each {|node| self[node]=random_point}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that you're not actually calling `initialize`, you're calling [`new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html#method-i-new), which then calls `initialize`. `new` throws away the return value of `initialize`, and instead always returns the object that was just created. This can be seen rather clearly in [the implementation of `Class#new`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_3_327/object.c#L1631).

Since you're already in the Hash you want, don't create another hash (`value`), simply use the one you're in (`self`)! This reduces your `initialize` to:

```
def initialize(node_list)
  node_list.each { |node| self[node] = random_point }
end
```